# Mapping Tool like EF Designer but for Data objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-objects

In trying to separate my domain layers and GUI and looking into all the different ways to do that, one thing that I keep asking is why is this so difficult?  Why all the extra code for data obejcts and then all the extra mapping of properties copying values in and out etc.  Shouldn't theere be an easier way?

Then I remeembered when i used to wite small littler db app using MS Access and, Access has the concept of a Dynaset, basically a Dynaset is a View, just like an SQL Server View, except it is an updateable view.  So, a MS Access form would be based of the View/Dynaset and therefore would not have to know the details of all the individual tables involved.  Sounds like the Data objects pattern to me.  Now, since Access has had this for 2 decades, shuoldn't there be a similar Dynaset, View, Mapping tools for Entity Framework, one that abstracts away the entities from the presentation?  Is there one I am not aware of?  3rd party?

Thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you may be looking for Entity Framework with POCO entities. You can find templates for them in the online gallery for templates (when you Add New Item in the project). Alternatively you can use right-click in your .edmx design view, select "Add code generation item" and pick the Fluent Generator.

These methods create multiple files instead of the default all-in-one EF generated file. One such file is the DbContext (as opposed to ObjectContext), one contains only entities (in the form of regular C# objects, no attributes or anything, just plain objects) and the last contains generated mapping in the form of fluent rules.

In this phase you can de-couple the entities file from its template and move it to another assembly. And voila, you have entities independent on the EF infrastructure. You can just pass the context these entities like you would before, and it'll do mapping by itself.

Alternatively you can use tool like **[AutoMapper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper)**, but you'll have to provide the mapping manually, which is a lot of work, but may be good in some cases.

Comment: Yes, I already use EF for POCO creation, but I am talking about the seperation of layers, so POCOS can not be visible in the presentation layer. AutoMapoper looks pretty close to what I was thinking excvept it looks like a 1 t o1 map, whereas i am envisioning more like a View where manty tavbles and field map to one result set that would be used by the GUI.  e.g.  Customer, Order, OrderItems, ShipMethod  => Would all maop to One OrdetrInfo object in the presetation Layer.

Comment: That sounds like very strict separation of layers, I personally prefer having POCO entities as the core of the application, shared by all layers - Data Persistence does DB mapping, presentation does DTO mapping, but still both layers can see those entites. As for the view-like mapping, I don't know of any such tool, sorry.

Comment: It is pretty standard MVC Enterprise software stuff.  But I do ageree it is mkuch easier to just use the entities themselves everywhere, but thats not so cool these days with Architects so...,

Answer (score 0):

Good design requires work.  If it was easy, everyone would do it automatically.  After all, everyone wants to do the least amount of work possible.

All the things you are complaining bout are part of the good design process, and there is no getting around them if you want a good design.

If you want to take shortcuts, then by all means, skip them.  It's your code.  nothing requires you to do things any specific way.

Access can do a lot of things because it's a desktop application, not a web application.  Web applications are fundamentally different from desktop applications in how you design them, how they work, and what issues you face with them.  For instance, the fact that you have a stateless environment and cannot keep result set from request to request makes many of the things people take for granted in Access impossible to do in a web app.

Specifically, if you want to use views, you can do so.  Views are updateable if they are properly designed, but typically require update statements that only affect one table in the view).  EF can work with views as well, but it has a lot of quirks you must deal with.

The data mapper pattern has emerged as a common pattern in web design because it's the easiest and straight forward way to have clean separation of concerns between layers and/or tiers.  I suggest you find ways to make them work within your development process.

It may also be that MVC is not the most appropriate framework for you to use.  It sounds more like you want to build Web apps the way you did Acceess, in which case Visual Studio Lightswitch may be a better choice for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff851953.aspx

Comment: I agree with everything you are saying, and the only "corner" I am trying to cut is the manual hand coding of the coping back and forth of all the field and the automatic binding that a View or Dynaset wuold have.  I am thinking of the same concept of how EF autopgenerates POCOS from the DB, why not also have a designer where you can then generate the View level objects that a mapped to those POCO's ??

Comment: @DjAMES - If you just want a designer, use the class designer.

Comment: No, I want more than a class designer.  i want a tool exactly like Entity Framework thsat sits on top of entity framework amd manages the data transfer back and forth between the POCOS and the high level data obejcts, and keep the obejcts in synch.

Comment: @DjAMES - it's very unlikely you'll see something like this because it's actually pretty specific.  Everyone does things slightly differently, and there isn't really a strong consensus on any specific way of doing it.  As such, you'll likely never see any major tools like that.  You might want to consider something like http://www.codesmithtools.com/